# C program doesn't work when using object in array json

Tags: c, json, object

In the following code,if I try to access pressure values when location is not there, then the code is working correctly. But if location key is included then it shows segmentation fault(core dumped) error. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Following is the data in json format and code in c language
Code :

Json File

```
 {
   "location": [
      {
          "location_type": "GPS",
          "lat": 19.123456,
          "lng": 72.123456,
          "ttf": 12
      },
      {
          "location_type": "WIFI",
          "wifiAccessPoints": [
              {
                  "macAddress": "AB:12:AC:13:AD:14",
                  "signalStrength": 0
              }
          ]
      }
    ],

"pressure": [
      30.02,
      30.29,
      29.13,
      28.99,
      28.43,
      27.11,
      27.99,
      27.46,
      26.11,
      26.04,
      25.27,
      24.55,
      24.35,
      23.87,
      22.76
    ]
}
```

C Code:

```
#include "json-c/json.h"

void main(){
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    struct json_object *parsed_json;

    struct json_object *imei;
    struct json_object *age;
    struct json_object *friends;
    struct json_object *friend;
    size_t n_friends;

    size_t i;   

    fp = fopen("json_trial2.json","r");
    fread(buffer, 1024, 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    parsed_json = json_tokener_parse(buffer);

    json_object_object_get_ex(parsed_json, "pressure", &friends);

     n_friends = json_object_array_length(friends);
     printf("Found %lu friends\n",n_friends);

     for(i=0;i<n_friends;i++) {`enter code here`
        friend = json_object_array_get_idx(friends, i);
        printf("%lu. %s\n",i+1,json_object_get_string(friend));
    }
return; 
}
```

Comment: A *debugger* will come in handy, *particularly* when it come to seg-faults and/or core dumps.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the correct format for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to print values of type `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: On a possible related note, add error checking and checks against null pointers.

Comment: Using `printf` without including a header is a bad idea and should cause some warings. Not related to the problem: Return type of `main` is supposed to be `int`.